# Save button doesnt save the image of the paint draw

Tags: java, button, save

in my java theres a save button that save the draw after finished drawing..

from Button java(updated) theres and error at drawingArea.saveImage();

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (e.getSource()==btnClear)
        drawingArea.clear();     
            else if (e.getSource()==infobutton)
            {
        //default title and icon
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Paint java created by bla bla bla bla bla blaa");
            }
            else if  (e.getSource()==colorBtn)
            {
                color = JColorChooser.showDialog(null,"LOL",color);
                drawingArea.setColorBtn(color);
            }
              else if  (e.getSource()==colorBg)
              {
                color = JColorChooser.showDialog(null,"LOL",color);
               drawingArea.setColorBg(color);
               drawingArea.repaint();
              }
                if(e.getSource()==save)
              {
                    drawingArea.saveImage();
        }

    }
```

and here is from DrawingArea java(updated)

```
public void saveImage(DrawingArea drawingArea)
           throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
   {
       BufferedImage image=new BufferedImage(drawingArea.getWidth(), drawingArea.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
       Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
       drawingArea.paint(g2);
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("/tmp/drawingArea.png"));
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Shouldn't you add something to `saveImage()` that *actually* saves something? So fare you are only asking the user for a path. That path then needs to be used.

Comment: its smth like this public void saveImage(BufferedImage img)
               throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
       {
           final String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File saved under " + dir + "/saveimage" + fileorder +".png");
                   fileorder+=1;
       }